# How can I style my blockquotes to look like this?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble finding a way to add yellow blockquotes to my quote without it indenting/adding unwanted line height.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Quotes]

Here's what I've tried:

```css
.contentquote {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.quote {
  line-height: color: #003b49;
  font-size: 2.9em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="contentquote"><span class="quote">&ldquo;</span>In my circles, when I talk to people about which firm is the best thinker in this (value-based care) area and which firm couples that with actual execution, we talk about Premier...<span class="quote">&rdquo;</span></h1>
```

Here's what I keep getting:

[image: Quotes 2]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You just have to put     `color: yellow;` on `.qoute`, right?

Comment: If you wrap your actual quote text in a tag (maybe a `<q>` tag?), you can use before and after pseudo-elements in your CSS so that you don’t have to include the quote `span`s in your HTML. Assign all of your shared properties (font, color, size, display, etc) to `q::before, q::after {}` and then assign the quote marks with `q::before {content:'“';}` and `q::after {content:'”';}`. The actual positioning for the quotes may take a little tweaking (see answers below), but this will save you a little markup and also improve accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

You have three problems with your code.

First, you have accidentally combined `line-height` and `color` as `line-height: color:`. You don't specify a `line-height` in your sample code, so I'm guessing the `line-height` is simply a typo. If you're actually using a `line-height`, you'll need to separate these out, using a semicolon.

Second, you forgot to **include** the font reference in addition to assigning it to `.contentquote`. The Roboto Slab font can be found at Google, and linked with `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">`.

Third, `#003b49` doesn't correlate to a yellowish orange; it correlates to a bluish green. You'll need to substitute this for the appropriate colour. The **exact** colour used in the example is `#fdb527`.

For the actual **positioning** of the quotes, you're looking to apply `position: absolute` to `.quote`. Set a negative `margin-top` on it to bring it down, inline with the text. Then use the pseudo-selector **[`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)** to shift the quote to the left of the text with a negative `margin-left` on `.quote:first-of-type`. Finally, to offset the negative margin, set a `padding-left` on `.contentquote`.

Here's a working example:

```css
.contentquote {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 22px;
}

.quote {
  color: #fdb527;
  font-size: 2.9em;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -16px;
}

.quote:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -22px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 class="contentquote"><span class="quote">&ldquo;</span>In my circles, when I talk to people about which firm is the best thinker in this (value-based care) area and which firm couples that with actual execution, we talk about Premier...<span class="quote">&rdquo;</span></h1>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The three issues you pointed out don't actually bring OP any closer to solving the problem: "I'm having trouble finding a way to add yellow blockquotes to my quote without it indenting/adding unwanted line height."

Comment: @JonUleis -- Initially missed that aspect. I've updated my answer now to cover this =]

Answer (score 1):

To solve your actual problem...

> I'm having trouble finding a way to add yellow blockquotes to my quote without it indenting/adding unwanted line height.

You can use `position: absolute` on the quotation marks to prevent them from interfering with the flow of the paragraph. I also indented the paragraph to create a gutter for the starting quotation mark.

```css
.contentquote {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.quote {
  color: #fdb527;
  font-size: 2.9em;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -16px;
}

.quote:first-child {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 class="contentquote"><span class="quote quote--start">&ldquo;</span>In my circles, when I talk to people about which firm is the best thinker in this (value-based care) area and which firm couples that with actual execution, we talk about Premier...<span class="quote">&rdquo;</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the code below. :)
```

In my part, I used CSS pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` to the quotes.

```css
*{ box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }

.contentquote {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 25px 56px 40px;
  background: #e4e4e4; 
  color: #575757;
  position:relative;
}
.contentquote p{ position: relative; display: inline-block; margin: 0; }
.contentquote p:before, .contentquote p:after{ color: #fdb527; font-size: 2.9em; position: absolute; }
.contentquote p:before{ left: -28px; top: -13px; content: "“"; }
.contentquote p:after{ bottom: -35px; content: "”"; }

.contentquote h2{ position: absolute; font-size: .7em; right: 28px; bottom: 18px; font-weight: normal; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="contentquote"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor do eiusmod tempor.</p><h2>Temporary Name</h2></div>
```